# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: json, reactjs, api, search, filter

I am trying to filter search my API data in react.js but I'm getting this error, cannot read property 'filter' of undefined. This is my JSON data link: https://alert-amigo-api.herokuapp.com/products/
Since the JSON data returns an array of objects, I have declared that in the props and used the same. What is the problem?

```
    import FilterResults from 'react-filter-search';
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    class UserProfile extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      products: [],
      value: ''
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            products: result.products
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
      console.log(this.state.products[0]);
  }
  handleChange = event => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ value });
  };
  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, products, value } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
      } else {
    return (
      <div className="content-margin">
        <input type="text" value={value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <FilterResults
          value={value}
          products={products}
          renderResults={products => (
            <div>
              {products.map(el => (
                 <div>
                  <span>{el.productName}</span>
                 </div>
               ))}
             </div>
           )}
         />
       </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
export default UserProfile;
```

Comment: I don't see any call to `.filter` in your code. Please include the error's stack and the code in which the `.filter` call happens.

Comment: @CherryDT `import FilterResults from 'react-filter-search';`

Comment: No, this is not what I mean. It says `Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`, but your code never accesses the property `filter` of anything. Again, please include the full error **stack** too.

Comment: @Manisha the array you want to filter is undefined, just console.log `products` probably.

Comment: @CherryDT the library does under the hood.

Comment: [`componentWillMount` is deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount). Use [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) to fetch data.

Answer (score 0):

By testing that exact example, you will notice that the fetch URL does not return products:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
```

The URL should be:

```
fetch('https://alert-amigo-api.herokuapp.com/products/')
```

Now `result.products` does contain an array. I suggest slightly bullet-proofing your code:

```
    (result) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        products: result.products || [] // <-- add empty array
      });
```

Or, if you prefer, on the render method:

```
render() {

  { products &&
    <FilterResults ... />
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry about the URL, that was by mistake. But I have changed the setState to what you have suggested (products: result.products || []). But still, I do not get the results. I get the same error:  "Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
filter
https://5vt5u.csb.app/node_modules/react-filter-search/lib/filter.js:20:15
FilterResults.render
https://5vt5u.csb.app/node_modules/react-filter-search/lib/index.js:36:56
finishClassComponent
https://5vt5u.csb.app/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18470:31"